# Error XML to Pandas DataFrame Conversion in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, pandas, dataframe, data-conversion

I want to convert the following XML file to a Pandas Data Frame, part of which is shown below.

```
<postlinks>
  <row Id="19" CreationDate="2010-04-26T02:59:48.130" PostId="109" RelatedPostId="32412" LinkTypeId="1" />
  <row Id="37" CreationDate="2010-04-26T02:59:48.600" PostId="1970" RelatedPostId="617600" LinkTypeId="1" />
  <row Id="42" CreationDate="2010-04-26T02:59:48.647" PostId="2154" RelatedPostId="2451138" LinkTypeId="1" />
  <row Id="52" CreationDate="2010-04-26T02:59:48.757" PostId="2572" RelatedPostId="209329" LinkTypeId="1" />
  <row Id="58" CreationDate="2010-04-26T02:59:48.943" PostId="3376" RelatedPostId="2187" LinkTypeId="1" />
  <row Id="59" CreationDate="2010-04-26T02:59:48.943" PostId="3376" RelatedPostId="18080" LinkTypeId="1" />
```

I have tried the following code but because the file size is too large (4 GB), it is either giving incorrect output or no output.

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('posts.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def f(elem, result):
    result[elem.tag] = elem.text
    cs = elem.getchildren()
    for c in cs:
        result = f(c, result)
    return result

d = f(root, {})
df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=['values']).T
df.head()
```

Output of the program is this.

```
values
Posts   \n
row None
```

Please provide me a solution to fix this. I have tried other stack overflow solutions but I am facing some or the other error.